# Нужна помощь с задачей на Си с матрицой

Tags: c, массивы, матрицы, динамические-массивы

Задача заключается в выводе квадратной  матрицы по спирали против часовой стрелки. Я написал для статической матрицы ,нужно изменить для динамической я попробовал но заменяя просто статическую на динамическую выводится только первый элемент.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int n;
   int i, j, x = 0, y = 0,w = n-1,l = 0; 
   // w - отступ от дального столбца l - от верхней строки
   srand(time(NULL)); 

   printf("Введите размер матрицы\n"); 
   scanf("%d",&n);
   int **mas = (int **)malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
       mas[i] = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));


   for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
       {
            mas[i][j] = rand() % 100;
            printf("%d ",mas[i][j] );
       }
    printf("\n");
   }

  for (i=0; i<n*n; ++i) 
  {
      printf("%d ", mas[x][y]);
      if ((y==(l+1))&&(x==l)) {w--;l++;} //условие перехода на внутренюю спираль
      if ((x==w)&&(y<w)) {y++;continue;} //вниз
      if ((x<w)&&(y==l)) {x++;continue;} //вправо
      if ((y==w)&&(x>l)) {x--;continue;} //влево
      if ((x==l)&&(y>l)) {y--;continue;} //вверх
  }

  return(0);
  }
```

Comment: Навскидку: `int n; /* ... */ int w = n-1` -- какое значение в этот момент у `n`? Правильно, неопределённое :)

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка здесь:

```
int n;
int i, j, x = 0, y = 0, w = n - 1, l = 0; 
                        ^^^^^^^^^
```

Переменная `w` инициализируется мусорным значением, так как значение `n` в этот момент не определено. Вот так всё работает:

```
scanf("%d",&n);
w = n - 1;

/* ... */

83 86 77 
15 93 35 
86 92 49 

83 15 86 92 49 35 77 86 93
```

Ну и надо бы добавить:

```
#include <time.h>    /* time() */
#include <stdlib.h>  /* malloc(),free(),srand(),rand() */
```